# How to replace multiple text in the column using Azure dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a column called "Location" in my data. I have 100000 records.

[image]

I am cleaning the location using the below code in the dataflow using derived column expression and naming the new column called "Location_new"

```
case(Location == 'Otago/Southland', "Otago",
    Location == 'Nelson - Marlborough', "Nelson",
    Location == 'National', "Other")
```

The code is working, however, it's not replacing and getting null for my entire new column

[image]

Please note, the above code is an example, I am replacing close to 250 names as my data is messy.

Can anyone advise how to overcome this? Is there any better way available for cleaning the data?

Comment: You need to also look at the input data (Location  field) to understand what's going on. I imagine that the value in Location does not satisfy any of your case statements and therefore returns NULL. I guess you need an `ELSE Location` statement in there to pass the location through as-is if it's valid.

Comment: As you surmise, having an enormous case statement is not a practical way to do htis. Ab better way is to have a lookup table. An even better way is to use some kind of fuzzy lookup. Probably the best way is to send your dataset to a vendor that does data washing and is an expert in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproed in with the sample. Your case statement looks fine and you are getting the NULL values in the new column might because your incoming data does not satisfy any of the case statements.

As Nick.McDermaid mentioned in the comments sections, you need to provide the else value in the case statement to get the incoming values as is when none of the conditions in the case statement works.

Case statement without else:

[image]

**Case statement with else:**

```
case(Location == 'Otago/Southland', "Otago",
Location == 'Nelson - Marlborough', "Nelson",
Location == 'National', "Other",
Location)
```

[image]